# Test in app purchaes

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am Testing my in-app purchase on my iphone4

i have created test users in iTunes Connect under Manage Users -> Test User -> Add New User.

But when I enter my Apple ID password(Test user), it always says "the apple id you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect".!

Comment: Did you log out of the store before launching your app and testing the In app purchase?

Comment: does it says you are in sandbox environment before login on alert?

Comment: i'm already log out in my iphone store

Comment: Have the same problem in iOS Simulator. Did you solve it?